Finding all elements of a finite vector space with GAP
I use the GAP package QPA, to calculate the Hom space between two modules $M$ ,$N$ of a quiver algebra over a finite field.
Then I want to obtain all elements in $Hom_A(M,N)$ and calcuate their rank as a linear map over $K$.

Question: What is the best way to do this?

Here an example with an approach:
K:=GF(3);A:=NakayamaAlgebra([3,2,1],GF(3));projA:=IndecProjectiveModules(A);
P0:=projA[1];P1:=projA[3];U:=HomOverAlgebra(P1,P0);V:=VectorSpace(K,U);

Now I have $U$ as a vector space.
But the command Elements(V) does not work. Is there any easy way to obtain all elements of $V$?

This looks as if the objects returned by HomOverAlgebra are missing some basic methods required for linear algebra operations. GAP runs in fallback code trying to find an isomorphic row space to $V$, and at some point element comparison fails.

The command HomOverAlgebra only produces a basis of homomorphisms of the Hom-space as a vectorspace over the field. They can be multiplied by scalars from the field and added together. But there is no structure for listing all the elements. This can be done in the following way:
gap> K := GF( 3 );
GF(3)
gap> A := NakayamaAlgebra( [ 3, 2, 1 ], GF( 3 ) );
<GF(3)[<quiver with 3 vertices and 2 arrows>]>
gap> projA := IndecProjectiveModules( A );
[ <[ 1, 1, 1 ]>, <[ 0, 1, 1 ]>, <[ 0, 0, 1 ]> ]
gap> P0 := projA[ 1 ]; 
<[ 1, 1, 1 ]>
gap> P1 := projA[ 3 ]; 
<[ 0, 0, 1 ]>
gap> U := HomOverAlgebra( P1, P0 );
[ <<[ 0, 0, 1 ]> ---> <[ 1, 1, 1 ]>> ]
gap> n := Length( U );
1
gap> allhoms := List( Elements( K^n ), v -> LinearCombination( U, v ) );
[ <<[ 0, 0, 1 ]> ---> <[ 1, 1, 1 ]>>, <<[ 0, 0, 1 ]> ---> <[ 1, 1, 1 ]>>, 
  <<[ 0, 0, 1 ]> ---> <[ 1, 1, 1 ]>> ]
gap> nullityandrank := List( allhoms, g -> [ Dimension( Kernel( g ) ), Dimension( Image( g ) ) ] );
[ [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ] ] 

I hope that these comments are helpful.
The QPA-team.
